# How to manipulate data.frame with position index and reconstruct desired one?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data.frame that consist of two different index vector, `query` named as `que`, `target` named as `subj`, is the result of searching overlapping of interval data of three individual data.frame simultaneously as an input (consider aligning three interval set by parallel). However, `inputDF` is the result of searching overlapping interval. I want to construct this data.frame with position index in a special way, such as reduce the dimension of `inputDF`, regroup the index and rebuild new data.frame which geometrically show pairs of the overlapping index.  Is there any way to manipulate `inputDF` and reconstruct my desired data.frame? Can anyone point me how to make this happen easily? Is there any efficient way to work with `inputDF` and build desired data.frame? Any idea?

Here is the visualization of interval aligning:

[image]

Here is the resulted example data.frame:

```
inputDF <- data.frame(
    que=c(5 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,14 ,16, 17 ,20 ,21, 22 , 8 , 9 ,16 ,22 , 2 ,12 ,15 ,18,
          21 , 4 , 3 , 7 ,15 ,21 ,13 ,19 , 4 , 5 , 6, 13, 14, 19 ,20, 2 , 3 ,12,
          18 , 6 , 5 ,11, 14, 20  ,8 ,16 ,22 , 9 ,17 , 1, 10 , 1 , 2 , 3, 11,12,
          18 , 1 ,10),
    subj=c( 5 , 7 , 8, 17 , 5 ,8 ,17 , 5 ,7 ,8, 22 ,22, 22, 22 , 2 ,2 ,15, 2,
            15  ,4  ,3 ,21 ,21 ,21 ,13 ,13 ,20 ,20 ,20 ,19 ,20 ,19 ,20 ,12 ,12 ,12,
            12 ,6 ,14 ,11 ,14 ,14 ,16 ,16 ,16 ,9  ,9  ,1  ,1 ,18 ,18 ,18 ,18 ,18, 18 ,10 ,10)
)
```

In order to build desired data.frame, I used `NA` to replace non-overlapped interval in `subj_2`;

This is my desired `data.frame` :

```
desiredDF <- data.frame(
    que=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22),
    self.subj=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22),
    subj_1=c(10,12,12,20,14,20,21,16,17,1,18,12,19,5,21,8,9,12,13,5,7,8),
    subj_2=c(18,18,18,NA,20,NA,NA,22,22,NA,NA,18,NA,20,NA,22,NA,18,NA,14,15,16)
)
```

**Edit** :

for example, these are interval data and how my desired data.frame constructed :

```
intDF <- list(
    bar=data.frame(start=c(8,18,33,53,69,81,105,115,135),
                   stop=c(14,21,39,61,73,87,111,120,153)),
    cat=data.frame(start=c(6,15,20,44,71,99,113,141),
                   stop=c(10,17,34,51,78,103,124,147)),
    foo=data.frame(start=c(11,43,57,101,117), 
                   stop=c(36,49,92,109,139))
)

intDF <- bind_rows(intDF)  # now it is easier to understand position index, such as `10`,`11` refers to 10th, 11th row in `intDF` and so on.

que self.sub subj1 subj2

1   1       10      18
2   2       12      18
3   3       12      18
4   4       20
5   5       14      20
6   6       20
7   7       21
8   8       16      22
```

How can I achieve my desired data.frame? Are there any efficient way to manipulate `inputDF`for building desired data.frame?

Comment: For each `que`, do you always have one and only one `subj` which is equal to itself?

Comment: @Psidom yes, that's the key point, basically, I could replicate `que` and rename it as `self_subj`. Could you give me the possible idea to make this happen? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Use `dcast`: `dcast(x[order(que != subj, que, subj)], que ~ rowid(que, prefix="subj"))`

Comment: @Arun Dear Arun, I added interval data and use `bind_rows` to get single data.frame `intDF`.  I have an error when applying your solution on my data.  Is that possible to make this happen by using base R as well? Thank you :)

Comment: @Arun I got an error when I applied your solution on my data: `object 'que' not found`, I used `inputDF` for variable `x` in your answer. Could you please point me how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using dplyr.

First we groupby your 'que', sort by 'subj', then set the columns to be the first and second subj which is not equal to the 'que':

```
library(dplyr)
inputDF %>%
 group_by(que) %>%
 arrange(subj) %>%
 summarise(self.sub = que[1], subj1 = subj[subj!=que][1], subj2 = subj[subj!=que][2])

Source: local data frame [22 x 4]

     que self.sub subj1 subj2
   (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1      1        1    10    18
2      2        2    12    18
3      3        3    12    18
4      4        4    20    NA
5      5        5    14    20
6      6        6    20    NA
7      7        7    21    NA
8      8        8    16    22
9      9        9    17    22
10    10       10     1    NA
..   ...      ...   ...   ...
```

In response to your edit, we can use the `IRanges` package:

```
library(IRanges)
myranges = IRanges(start = intDF$start, end = intDF$stop)
data = as.data.frame(findOverlaps(myranges))
data
   queryHits subjectHits
1          1          10
2          1           1
3          1          18
4          2          18
5          2           2
6          2          12
7          3          18
8          3          12
9          3           3
10         4           4
...       ...         ...
```

Comment: Dear jeremycg, I used `bind_rows` to get single DF `intDF`, then proceed searching overlap, `inputDF` as result of the overlapping interval with position index (numeric index refers to row). Based on my update, is that possible to make this happen in base R as well? Thank you :) –

Comment: See the edit, it is possible in base R, but much easier in the IRanges package

Comment: Yes, using `IRanges` package I'll get `inputDF`, but how can I change `inputDF` to my desired one? Is that possible to see base R solution as well ? Thank you very much :)